# How do I start a Docker container in custom network namespace?

Tags: linux, docker, namespace, network-namespaces

How do I make `docker run` to `setns` to the network namespace of my choice when starting a container? I want something like `--net host` mode, but aiming to the namespace of Docker server itself.

Or should I [`nsenter(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html) from within the container started with `--net host`? Can it be done without making the container overly privileged?

Comment: @PhilipCouling, Host has multiple manually created network namespaces. One of them contains `dockers` / `containerd`. Obviously, that is the namespace where `--net host` containers are started by default.

Comment: It is already possible with `--privileged` `--net host` container + mounting (`-v`) the network namespace into the container + `nsenter` within the container. Maybe Docker supports specifying some additional wrappers while container's is still in host filesystem and hasn't yet dropped privileges. That would make the scheme nicer + remove `--privileged` from the container itself.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm saying ... the thing responsible for networking prior to dropping privileges is the network driver but *i don't think* the default one (`host`) has this functionality built in. The other built-in drivers aren't what you're asking for.  It would be especially tricky to implement because container configuration defined when you type `docker run ...` lives across server reboots.  AFAIK network namespaces don't and their numbering is completely lost on reboot.  So the driver would need some *stable* way to configure which namespace you wanted.

Comment: Network (and other) namespaces can be mounted to files. Those files can be specified to e.g. `nsenter` and can have persistent names. I expect the driver to be almost same as `host`, but accepting an additional argument and doing two additional syscalls: `open(2)` and `setns(2)`.